# Having Restangular's .remove send data in body vs URI

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am in the process of converting my Angular REST calls to utilize Restangular. During this conversion I am simply moving the calls to use Restangular.one('controller').remove(object); This is calling the correct URI and method DELETE but is sending the object in the URI instead of the body. Is there an easy way to tell Restangular to send the object in the body? For POST/PUT I have utilized customPOST and customPUT which send the data in the body. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `customDELETE` for that :).

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: I can't find an example of using .customDELETE with body in your wiki. Can you demonstrate it here?