# Restangular DELETE request, send data in body

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using restangular to send DELETE request. 
I send some data in the request, and data is added to query string. But I want to use body instead of URI. I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643182/having-restangulars-remove-send-data-in-body-vs-uri) on stackoverflow. [Mgonto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385982/mgonto) said, that this problem can be resolved, by using `customDELETE` method. 
I've tried something like this:

```
Restangular.all("all").customDELETE("one", {
firstParam: 1,
secondParam: 2
});
```

Unfortunately parameters still sent in the URI.
Is there any way to send parameters in body?? Like in POST request??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My teamlead helped me to find a solution!
We can use `customOperation` to send data in body of our request.
Here's an example:

```
Restangular.all("all/one").customOperation("remove", null, null, {
firstParam: 1,
secondParam: 2
});
```

It works fine for me! 
Hope it'll help someone!

Comment: Worked for me as well, thanks Sergey. I used `.customOperation('remove', '', {}, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body);`

Comment: For some reason, the main answer did not work.  Thanks, @AzaFromKaza, your solution worked for me.